# Accessing form variables from user control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that consists of several forms. There is a MainForm and then other forms open up within this MainForm. One of the child forms that opens up (we'll just call it Form1) contains a user control that has controls inside it, such as a datagrid view. This datagridview control has several events that are triggered, one being a "cellclick" event.

This click event must access a public timer object that is declared in Form1.

Currently just to make it work I used the code:

```
((Form1)this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent).clickTimer.Start();
```

However this doesn't seem like the best way I could be accessing this Timer object, and could potentially be a headache for future development of Form1 and its User Controls.

What are alternative ways of accessing my Form1 timer from inside the user control's datagridview click event?

Any advice is appreciated as I'm drawing a blank on this right now.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the design; I'd strive to make child controls independent of their parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out more elegant way to access my Form1 object(as opposed to use Parent.Parent.Parent...etc.) with:

`Control activeForm = this.FindForm();`

So now I have:

```
((Form1)activeForm).clickTimer.Start();
```

The above code gives me the form the userControl exists inside(Form1), and since the Forms that the UC exists inside will always have a Timer, this should work even if the user control is placed on a different form (say Form2).

However, @Darin did provide a good alternative, but I chose to use my solution because it provided me the quickest way to fix my issue with least amount of code changes required yet still provides low maintainability for my Forms. Specific to my situation, of course.

Comment: PS - thanks for the advice..just needed to get my brain working.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the user control take the Timer instance as constructor argument and store it in a private backing field for future access.

Comment: This can be a problem when using the Forms Designer.

Comment: @Erno Not if you leave the default constructor how it is, but add a new one for your own use.

Comment: @AlexanderR - how would you use both?

Comment: Wouldn't I have to change my Form1 designer to use the overloaded constructor? Currently that is the only place the user control is called.

Comment: You have two constructors on the user control, one - the default autogenerated one - that takes no parameters, and the other, which takes a Timer object. Then just call the one that you want in code. Of course, you'll need to handle the timer field not being initialised in the rest of the class.

Comment: @Encryption Yes, you'd have to manually instanciate it. Another option might be to expose a `Timer` property on the user control, that you set from Form1... something like `userControl.Timer = this.clickTimer;`.

Comment: hmm..my problem with setting from Form1 is that no actual code is executed on form1 whenever this datagridview or any eventin the UserControl is fired. The Timer has events on the Form1 that I would like to just keep working on Form1. I suppose I could try the overloaded approach.

Comment: Well I figured out more elegant way (as opposed to use Parent.Parent...) with Control activeForm = this.FindForm(); That gives me the form the userControl exists inside, and since the forms the UC exists inside will always have a Timer this should work.

Comment: @Erno, you use both by calling the default constructor from your parameterized constructor: `public Form1(Timer timer) : this() { _timer = timer; }`

Comment: @phoog - If you drag and drop the usercontrol on the form, the default constructor is added to the generated code in the InitializeComponent. In my opinion it is too easy to forget to add the call to the custom constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static event in the child form and register to it in the parent form.

Trigger the event on "cellclick" and trigger the timer in the event handler on your parent form.